# Preventing local pointers

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-warnings

Maybe it's a newbie question, but is there a method in C/C++ to prevent a function from accepting a pointer to a local variable?

Consider this code:

```
int* fun(void)
{
 int a;
 return &a;
}
```

The compiler will generate a warning that the pointer can not be returned. Now consider this:

```
int* g;

void save(int* a)
{
 g = a;
}

void bad(void)
{
 int a;
 save(&a);
}
```

This will pass through the compiler without a warning, which is bad. Is there an attribute or something to prevent this from happening? I.e. something like:

```
void save(int __this_pointer_must_not_be_local__ * a)
{
 g = a;
}
```

Thanks in advance if someone knows the answer.

Comment: code reviews? ...code profilers such as lint?

Comment: Code reviews, static analysis. What you are asking for is in fact very, very complex.

Comment: What if I wanted to do `void f() { int b; save(&b); /* do stuff */ save(NULL); }` ?  It's not necessarily the fact the variable is "local" that matters; This would also be bad. `int* p = new int(); save(p); delete p;`

Comment: @CharlesBailey: There are lots of things that are bad; OP is asking about a particular one, which the compiler already seems to have the ability to recognize (the logic used to warn about returning a local pointer).

Comment: @ScottHunter: My point is that storing a pointer to a local object is not necessarily bad. Flagging it as wrong will generate false positives.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: The OP was about flagging when it WOULD be bad, so the compiler can perform a check similar to one it already makes, not relying on the compiler to figure it out when it make that check.

Comment: The question asked for a method to prevent a function from accepting a pointer to a local object. I was just pointing out that this is almost never a universally wrong thing to need to prevent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no reliable and portable way to tell a pointer to local from a pointer to a heap object. There is no way to declaratively prevent this, either.

There are hacks dependent on the memory layout of your particular system that work at runtime by invoking unspecified behavior (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054756/335858) for an example), but you are on your own if you decide to give them a try.

Comment: But if the compiler cam recognize when a function is trying to return a local pointer, and if there were an attribute as the OP suggests, why couldn't the compiler use the same logic to generate a warning?

Comment: @ScottHunter Because the compiler cannot reliably determine it by statically analyzing the code. Storing a pointer in a global variable is only one way that you can circumvent the check - you can store it in a struct member, convert to an array of bytes, and so on. Adding a check so unreliable would defeat the purpose.

Comment: How is that different from the return check, which IS implemented?

Comment: @Scott. Because the compiler knows that the returned pointer will no longer be valid after the "return". In the other cases it simply can't reliably determine if the pointer will be used after the end of the function. The result will be either useless warnings for false positives (that one would start ignoring very soon) or missed cases (that would defeat the purpose). For avoiding shooting in the foot, is much better aiming right than having the gun not working when pointing down.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one way for debug build using debug heap (default):

```
//d:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio ?\VC\crt\src\dbgint.h
\#define nNoMansLandSize 4
typedef struct _CrtMemBlockHeader
{
    struct _CrtMemBlockHeader * pBlockHeaderNext;
    struct _CrtMemBlockHeader * pBlockHeaderPrev;
    char *                      szFileName;
    int                         nLine;
    size_t                      nDataSize;
    int                         nBlockUse;
    long                        lRequest;
    unsigned char               gap[nNoMansLandSize];
    /* followed by:
     *  unsigned char           data[nDataSize];
     *  unsigned char           anotherGap[nNoMansLandSize];
     */
} _CrtMemBlockHeader;
\#define pbData(pblock) ((unsigned char *)((_CrtMemBlockHeader *)pblock + 1))
```

There is a allocation header, which ends with gap, so there is not big probability there will be 0xFDFDFDFD before the pointer - not perfect, but may help...

```
if (\*((int\*)pointer-1) == 0xFDFDFD) { // stack pointer }
```